# Analysis of CPU Load with JProfiler

Tags: java, jvm, jprofiler

I would like to evaluate my CPU usage of my Java web application with the JProfiler in "sampling" mode.The application is based on the Spring boot framework.

However, JProfiler always shows a CPU usage of 9%-11%. However, there is practically nothing going on on the server. There are no requests to the application and the CPU usage never approaches 0%, but remains at 9%-11%. I would have expected the CPU usage to drop below 9% as well.
In the "Thread History" overview, all threads are in the "Waiting" or "Net I/O" status.
Could it be that this usage is the overhead created by the JProfiler?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, the main purpose of a profiler is to show where CPU time is spent. Does JProfiler show where these 9-11% come from? Also, are you sure that CPU is not used by some other process? (check `top` or the Task Manager, depending on your OS).

Comment: According to the JProfiler, there are no currently running threads. All threads are in the status "Waiting" or "Net I/O". Via "top" you can see that other applications also consume CPU, but the JProfiler should actually only show the CPU load of the JVM to be analysed, or is the basic load of the host also shown there?

Comment: The "CPU Load" telemetry shows "System load" and "Process load". Which of the two is at 9 to 11%?

Comment: Our version (9.2.1) of JProfiler only shows "CPU load". If I start the application without the JProfiler, the `top`-command says that the CPU load is virtually 0, so I assume that the load seen is generated by the JProfiler and the metric determination itself.